Has D. Trump mentioned whether he'd be willing to debate K. Harris?
News is that J. Biden dropped out of the 2024 race, and that he endorsed VP K. Harris. How much delegates have to or will follow Biden's wishes is somewhat debated though, at this point. N.B., the change is pretty official as far as the campaign naming goes though:

Biden’s presidential campaign formally renamed itself “Harris for President,” according to paperwork filed with the Federal Election Commission within hours of Biden’s announcement.

I'm curious if Trump considers Harris the Dem. counter-candidate at this point though. Has he said anything whether he'd be willing to debate Harris?
FWTW, Politico suggests the answer is "no":

One GOP source tells me he doubts Trump will debate Vice President Kamala Harris — he'll likely call her an illegitimate candidate.

I'm looking for a more 'official' stance than one anonymous "GOP source" though. Possibly Trump will make a statement/commitment in the following hours or days.
N.B. the pro-Trump PACs are definitely not ignoring this:

Minutes after Biden dropped out of the 2024 presidential race and announced he was endorsing Harris, MAGA Inc., the principal pro-Trump super PAC, said it was immediately launching Harris-focused commercials in Pennsylvania, Georgia and Arizona, with one ad saying Harris was “in on it” and had “covered up Joe Biden’s obvious mental decline.”

But I'm looking for Trump's personal stance in re debates, in particular.

As the news just broke that Biden has dropped out of the race and Kamala Harris is just one name that has been put forward it seems s to early to answer. There is unlikely to be any news about another debate until after the Democratic nominee is decided and finalized.

VtC as this is explicitly asking for Trump's personal stance, which is already, also explicitly, a reason for closure.

I disagree that asking for a personal stance is bad. But posting propaganda masked as question is clearly bad. Hard to say, what to do. The ultimate result will be, very likely, a single-sided propaganda site, roughly what also wikipedia is doing on the political line.

Trump's "official" stance is clearly a wait and see how things are going but he did indicate that he is no longer bound to his debate agreements. He posted on Truth Social:

My debate with Crooked Joe Biden, the Worst President in the history of the United States, was slated to be broadcast on Fake News ABC, the home of George Slopadopolus, sometime in September. Now that Joe has, not surprisingly, quit the race, I think the Debate, with whomever the Radical Left Democrats choose, should be held on FoxNews, rather than very biased ABC. Thank you! DJT

In other words he is not committing to and not ruling out the possibility of debating whoever the Democratic nominee will be.
https://deadline.com/2024/07/trump-debate-kamala-harris-abc-news-1236017141/

DJT refuses to accept his agreement to debate Mr. Biden as obligating him to debate another candidate under the same terms. In the quotation presented, however, he does seem to suppose that he will debate the Democrat nominee, once there is one.  There is nothing surprising or unusual about him wanting to do that under the most favorable terms he can obtain.

Lots of comments deleted. Please keep your comments relevant to the question.

FWTW, the (earlier) Trump statement was today supplemented by one from his campaign:

"General election debate details cannot be finalized until Democrats formally decide on their nominee ... it would be inappropriate to schedule things with Harris because Democrats very well could still change their minds," Trump campaign spokesman Steven Cheung said in a statement.

(AP appears to have slightly rearranged the order of statements in that quote, but the gist of it seems right, given the longer take in NYT. I'm not sure where the original is/was posted.)

Trump himself has now (August 3) made it more clear he won't be debating on ABC. So, right now, both candidates agree to debate... just not on the same network:

"I have agreed with FoxNews to debate Kamala Harris on Wednesday, September 4th. The Debate was previously scheduled against Sleepy Joe Biden on ABC, but has been terminated in that Biden will no longer be a participant, and I am in litigation against ABC Network and George Slopadopoulos, thereby creating a conflict of interest," he said.


This is why I mentioned it was to soon to look for an answer when the question was posted as he has already changed his mind on the debate in a few days after saying he would still do it.

It should be noted that it is a one sided agreement as Kamala Harris hasn't agreed to anything. It should also be noted that he is wanting some of the rules changed as well.

FWTW, if someone wonders, the Trump lawsuit against ABC is over
the “liable for rape” statement by Stephanopoulos  https://www.pbs.org/newshour/politics/trump-plans-to-skip-abc-debate-with-harris-in-september-insists-on-earlier-fox-news-faceoff#:~:text=Trump%20sued%20the%20network%20in,claim%20that%20she%20was%20raped. OTOH, AP points out that the debate with Biden on ABC had been agreed after & despite that.
